# Efficient linguistic processing in R

Tags: r, vector, linguistics

I'm having the following problem:

I have a set of words for which I need normative frequencies. The list counts 350 words. I have another list, let's call it frequency list, with over 5.5 million different words and their corresponding normative absolute frequencies.

Now, I need the frequencies for these 350 words. I wanted to work with this code in R, but it takes my MacBook about 7 minutes just to load the frequency list.

```
#Read data
decow <- read.table("decow14ax.freq10.w.tsv", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

#Converting wordlist in lower case
decow$token_lowercase <- tolower(as.character(decow$token...)) 

#Read word list
wordlist <- read.csv("wordlist.csv") 

#Set frequency counter to 0
wordlist$norm_frequency = 0  

#Obtaining frequencies for word list from norm database
for (i in 1:nrow(wordlist))                                               
{ 
  for (j in 1:nrow(decow_small)) {
    if (wordlist$word[i]==decow$token_lowercase[j]) {
    wordlist$norm_frequency[i] <- decow_small$f_raw[j]}
  }
}
```

I noticed that this code is not very efficient. Instead I would like to work with a vector because my guess is that it will prevent me from having to realize this loop 350 times and thus keeping my laptop busy during hours.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tm)
library(janeaustenr)
wordlist<-janeaustenr::emma
wordlist<-sample(wordlist,50)
wordlist<-tokenizers::tokenize_words(wordlist)
wordlist<-unlist(wordlist)
wordlist<-removeWords(wordlist,stopwords('english'))
wordlist<-table(wordlist)[-1]
wordlist
```

This a sample to show you the `table()` function provides a frequency.

The library(tm) is to use `removeWords()` and the `[-1]` is to remove the `""` count from the table.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Michael. The problem are not the frequencies, they are already accessible. I just don't want to look up 350 words in a file. That's why I wrote that little script. It is just not very efficient and takes probably a day to compute. Also, in the example you provided there is just one list. I have two. A 5.5 million word list with frequencies and a 350 word list.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a solution which will, most likely, be faster than my previous approach:

```
#Create word vector containing all entries from word list
wordvec1 <- unname(unlist(sapply(wordlist$word, function(z) str_split(tolower(z), " "))))

#Create empty word vector with length of word vector 1
wordvec2 <- rep(0,length(wordvec1))

#Iteration
for (i in 1:length(wordvec1)) {
wordvec2[i] <- wordvec2[i]+sum(decow$f_raw[decow$token_lowercase==wordvec1[i]])
}
```

Any ideas for improvement are gladly appreciated.